# Simple list of images Android (like gallery)

Tags: android

I need to make ListView with images; images are stored on SDCard and I need to load it using URI. It isn't problem for me. But there is the following problem: I add 10 images into drawable and make simple adapter for ListView:

```
private class PointImagesAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Integer> {
    private static final int LAYOUT_ID=R.layout.adapter_point_images;    
    private Integer[] ii;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private List<ImageInfo> images;

    public PointImagesAdapter(Integer[] ii) {
        super(MainActivity.this, LAYOUT_ID, ii);
        this.ii=ii;
        inflater=LayoutInflater.from(MainActivity.this);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View view, ViewGroup group) {
        if (view==null) {
            view=inflater.inflate(LAYOUT_ID, null);
        }
        ImageView i=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.adapterPointImagesItem);
        i.setImageResource(ii[position]);
        return view;
    }
}
```

It works, but all images has got a big resolution (2048x1536), and ListView is scrolling very slow:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/dialogViewImagesList"
    android:layout_width="100dip"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:cacheColorHint="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fastScrollEnabled="true"
    android:persistentDrawingCache="scrolling"
    android:scrollingCache="false" >
</ListView>
```

I think problem is big resolution. How can I fix it? Thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/load-bitmap.html. Check the topic Load a scaled down version in memory

Answer (score 0):

1st : You can extract the image in the form of Bitmap.
2nd : Convert the bitmap into scaled Bitmap with reduced dimensions.

```
   Bitpmap bm = BitmapFactory.decode ("image file path");
   bm.setDensity(integer);
   Bitmap bm1 = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (bm, width, height, false);
   ImageView i=(ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.adapterPointImagesItem);
   i.setImageBitmap(bm1);
```

This will internally reduce the size of Image to show in listView at run time.